# Is there a per user wallpaper folder?

Tags: desktop-background

I have found that most of the system-wide folders and configurations have a per-user counterpart.  Can someone advise me if this also goes for the wallpapers.

Examples are:

```
Name               System-Wide                 Per-User
==========================================================================
Applications       /usr/share/applications     ~/.local/share/applications
Themes             /usr/share/themes           ~/.themes
Fonts              /usr/share/fonts            ~/.fonts
Wallpaper          /usr/share/backgrounds      ~/?????
```

For backgrounds I tried both `~/.local/share/backgrounds` and `~/.backgrounds`, neither works.  I'm still trying to find the per-user area for this folder.  If none exist I can stop looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a per user wallpaper area. You can get to it by:

```
(right click on the) Desktop -> (Click) Change Desktop background 
(on the Wallpapers drop-down select) Pictures.
```

The background images are the pictures in your default `~/Pictures` folder.

Answer (score 1):

I founded in my ubuntu 22.04 in `~/.local/share/backgrounds`